# How to zip folder without full path

Tags: php, linux, zip, directory

firstly I don't which is the correct stackExchange site to post this question if the question is for other stack-site please remove my question.

**Now let talk about the question:** This situation is I have a file which is located in: `/home/user/public_html/folder-one/folder-two/folder-three/file.php` and the file must create archive of folder `/folder-one` with all files and sub-folders of `/folder-one`. I create the archive with system function (exec(), shell_exec() or system()) and it works perfect. My code is:

```
<?php
$output = 'zip -rq my-zip.zip /home/user/public_html/folder-one -x missthis/\*';
shell_exec($output);
?>
```

But when I download and open the archive the archive include the sub-folders as `/home` ; `/user` ; `/public_html` but this folders are totally unneeded and I wanna know how to create zip without them.

When I try with something like this `$output = 'zip -rq my-zip.zip ../../../folder-one -x missthis/\*';` but then when I open the archive (on Windows 7 based OS) the name of folder-one is `../folder-one`

**Postscript: It will be better if somebody gives me correct** `$output` **the make zips on windows based hosting plans.**

Best regards,
George!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, zip will store the full path relative  to the current directory. So you have to `cd` into `public_html` before running `zip`:

```
$output = 'cd /home/user/public_html; zip -rq my-zip.zip folder-one -x missthis/\*';
shell_exec($output);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a better way, without doing a `cd` . As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9710181/4501084) there is an option to ignore full paths. This is `-j` or `--junk-paths`. So you could do:

```
<?php
$output = 'zip -jrq my-zip.zip /home/user/public_html/folder-one -x missthis/\*';
shell_exec($output);
?>
```

Comment: -j will leave `/folder_one` out, and it sounds like OP needs to have that directory and its contents in the zip archive, not just the contents of the folder