# how can i search for files and zip them in one zip file

Tags: linux, operating-system

I tried to search files and zip them with the following commmand

```
find . regexpression -exec zip {} \;
```

however it is not working. How can i do this?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The command you use will run zip on each file separately, try this:

```
find . -name <name> -print | zip newZipFile.zip -@
```

The `-@` tells zip to read files from the input. From man [zip(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip),

> **`-@` file lists.** If a file list is specified as `-@` [Not on MacOS], zip takes the list of input files from standard input instead of from the command line.

Comment: can i remove the files in this command which are being zipped as well??? or i will have to give another command like find . -name <name> -exec rm -rf {} \; to remove zipped files

Comment: @LOGAN the easiest way would be to do that, to run another command, but maybe there's a better way to do it, you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: Just tried on a Mac, works like a charm. I guess you can remove the disclaimer

Comment: That disclaimer comes from the manpage, even on macOS, but indeed the `-@` option works.

Comment: Based on that It's how I zip changes `find . -cmin -400 -print | zip newZipFile.zip -q@`.

Comment: One may omit `-print` as by default `find` prints found files.

Answer (score 23):

Your response is close, but this might work better:

```
find -regex 'regex' -exec zip filname.zip {} +
```

That will put all the matching files in one zip file called filename.zip. You don't have to worry about special characters in the filename (like a line break), which you would if you piped the results.

Comment: do what? with the + sign

Comment: @aliopi The + means to replace the {} with all of the filenames, rather than execute the command once for each file.

Comment: If you perform a search in an external directory, the result may be something like `home/path/file`. in that case it is necessary to use `zip -j`  more info here [create-zip-ignore-directory-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710141/create-zip-ignore-directory-structure)

Answer (score 16):

You can also provide the names as the result of your find command:

```
zip name.zip `find . -name <name> -print`
```

This is a feature of the shell you are using.  You can search for "backticks" to determine how your shell handles this.