# How to zip a folder, but minus the files using zip command line

Tags: zip

I am creating a zip file of my application tree, minus folders that have temporary files. For now I exclude the folders using -x option and manually created them with  unzip. Is there a way with zip to exclude the files but include the folder (i.e. it would be an empty folder in the zip file?)

I am using

```
zip -r zipfile.zip . -x appsessions/\* workfolder/\*
```

but of course it excludes the folders and files in them. I would like to keep appsessions/ and workfolder/ in the zip file, but empty.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this:

```
find . -type d -print | zip name.zip -@
```

Also check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13234936/1135424