# Download git Archive (as .zip) without root-folder

Tags: git, github, gitlab, minecraft, git-archive

My question is very similar, to another very old question ([Download GitHub .zip without Repository's name folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834928/download-github-zip-without-repositorys-name-folder)), which was closed without a solution that works for me.

So I write a fresh question, with all information, I already could gather.

I'd like to find a way to download zip files (of any state of the projects) from GitHub / GitLab repositories.
Currently you CAN download .zipfiles from GitHub and GitLab repositories via Code -> Download zip

My Problem in the current state is, that the archives always contain a folder with repository name and branch at the top level e.g.

```
master.zip
  - myRepo-master
    - README
    - other file in repo root
```

But e.g. for minecraft datapacks, resourcepacks or mods etc. you need to have a fixed structure, what means the zipfile can not be used with this root folder and always must be repacked, before in could be used.

From [GitHub Docs - Downloading Archives](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/using-files/downloading-source-code-archives) I know, that the archive function is created via the `git archive` command.
I already could modify the contents of the archives using a `.gitattributes` files in my repo (read more about this at [git-scm - Git Archive - Attributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#ATTRIBUTES) )

Unfortunately I could not find a way a configuration to avoid this folder in the root of the zip-file.

I found some workarounds for this issue e.g.

- to add my downloads as Releases, but the always requires Manually adding a new Version and repacking the zipfile
- or several pages like e.g. [DownGit](https://github.com/MinhasKamal/DownGit)

But nothing of this is what I want. I want to configure my own repository that

- the archive that you can download foreach state of the project is packed without root folder
- OR that I have a native URL to GitHub or GitLab, where you could download a archive (without root folder) directly without 3rd party pages

**So the Question is:**
Can anybody give some helpful information how to change the download behavior in GitLab / GitHub to get an archive without root folder?

My biggest hope was to find using `.gitattribues` to exclude files and the parent folder.
Excluding files or subfolders already works like you can see at my [bundle-recipe Datapack](https://gitlab.com/games8472/minecraft/data/bundle-recipe).

Has anyone helpful ideas to exclude the top folder too?

Comment: "*Can anybody give some helpfull informations how to change the downlod behavior in gitlab / github to get an archiv without root folder?*" Nope, no way. The only solution is to clone and archive locally like this: `git clone --depth=1 URL/repo.git && git archive --remote=./repo -o repo.zip HEAD && rm -rf repo`

Comment: "but the always requires Manually adding a new Version and repacking the zipfile" -- no it doesn't. You could set up an automatied [workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows) that would produce these archives for you whenever you update the repository.

Comment: @larsks You are right, but even If I woul make an workflow, it wohl be crazy to create a new release for each commit.

I hoped to find a way to fix the build-in zip download

Comment: You don't need to make a new release for each commit. You can attach generated artifacts to your CI runs. You don't need to make this complicated.