# Using bash zip from within target directory vs from outside

Tags: bash

Let's say I'm in ~ and I want to zip the contents of the directory ~/folder-to-zip

I can cd into folder-to-zip and type `zip -r9 ../zipped.zip *` and that produces the result I want.

I wanted to do the same thing without having to cd out of ~. So from ~ I tried `zip -r9 zipped.zip folder-to-zip/*` but this produced a slightly different zip file. Are these commands not doing the same thing?

Comment: This might help: [create zip - ignore directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9710141/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these commands act differently. When you use `zip` it will by keep the paths relative to how you ran the command, so running zip from different working directories will affect the result.

#### Example:

```
.
└── test
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    ├── file3
    └── foo
        ├── file4
        └── file5
```

If I am in the root directory in this example and use the following command:

```
zip -r test.zip test/*
```

I get the following result:

```
$ unzip -l test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   test/file1
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   test/file2
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   test/file3
        0  2019-11-08 16:53   test/foo/
        0  2019-11-08 16:52   test/foo/file4
        0  2019-11-08 16:53   test/foo/file5
---------                     -------
        0                     6 files
```

However if I change directory into `test`, and this command:

```
cd test
zip -r ../test2.zip *
```

I get the following zip file:

```
$ unzip -l test2.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   file1
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   file2
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   file3
        0  2019-11-08 16:53   foo/
        0  2019-11-08 16:52   foo/file4
        0  2019-11-08 16:53   foo/file5
---------                     -------
        0                     6 files
```

---

#### Aside:

As an aside, if you do not have a directory structure, you can specify `-j` which will remove all paths and store the files all in the root of the zip file:

```
# from the root of the example structure
zip -j test3.zip test/*
```

Produces:

```
$ unzip -l test3.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   file1
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   file2
        0  2019-11-08 16:51   file3
        0  2019-11-08 16:52   file4
        0  2019-11-08 16:53   file5
---------                     -------
        0                     5 files
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you do not want to move from ~. Assuming you do not want to worry about getting back to ~ after the zip, you can place cd+zip into sub shell.

```
(cd ~/folder-to-zip && zip -r9 ../zipped.zip *)
```

For the specific case that folder-to-zip does not have sub folder, you can try the '-j' (junk-paths), which will flatten the hierarchy

```
zip -j -r9 zipped.zip -9 folder-to-zip/*
```

**Update 1:**

Based on clarification (see comments below), there is generic pattern to to follow, using sub-shell, when the result zip file is relative to the starting folder (e.g., place the output in the original folder).

```
# Bash Only (using OLDPWD)
(cd /path/to/folder/to/zip && zip -r9 $OLDPWD/zipped.zip *)

# Posix (using initial PWD, instead of OLDPWD)
(HERE=$PWD ; cd /path/to/folder/to/zip && zip -r9 $HERE/zipped.zip *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing the sub shell. PS: I didn't want to move directory because it was 4 folders deep and I need to be zipping it each time I make changes to one of the files and want to create a deployment package. So I created a bash script to make it easy.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare I've added few examples which might be helpful to you situation.